# remover arquitecturas en apk flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, compilar

estoy desarrollando una app en flutter, y soy nuevo en el lenguaje. noté que al compilar la app, cuando ejecuto el comando

```
flutter build apk --release
```

genera el apk pero dentro de la carpeta lib, tiene 6 arquitecturas`x86`, `x86_64`, `mips`, `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64_v8a`. De todas esas arquitecturas tengo entendido que solamente son necesarias las dos ultimas para subirla al playstore, el problema es que la app compilada de esa manera pesa **140MB**, lo cual es excesivo, por lo que mi pregunta es. ¿Como puedo hacer para que no me compile las otras 4 arquitecturas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para subir una app a la Google Play Store, ahora tienes que generar un AppBundle en lugar de una Apk. Esto te generará un solo archivo con formato .aab, y el peso de la app estará mejor optimizado.

Utiliza el comando: `flutter build appbundle`

Y con ese archivo no tendras que preocuparte por las arquitecturas.
Te recomiendo leas la documentacion en: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android para que te informes mejor.